# Android compare special letters

Tags: java, android, sorting, comparator

Is there a way to correctly sort international strings in Android? I use a custom comparator, and a `compareTo()` method, but it's not enough for me. I want letters like this "ö" to be displayed near "o", but all of them are at the end of the list. How can I force the comparator to think they are similar to "o, a, etc..."?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To locale-sensitive string comaprision use [`Collator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html). From docs:

> Performs locale-sensitive string comparison. A concrete subclass,
>   RuleBasedCollator, allows customization of the collation ordering by
>   the use of rule sets.

Example of comparing strings:

```
 Collator deCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY); // or new Locale("pl", "PL") for polish locale ;)
 System.out.println(deCollator.compare("abcö", "abco"));
```

prints `1`.

---

If you want to sort list of strings using above collator, you can write:

```
final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
        "über", "zahlen", "können", "kreativ", "Äther", "Österreich");
Collections.sort(strings, deCollator); // Collator implements Comparator
System.out.println(strings);
```

prints:

```
[Äther, können, kreativ, Österreich, über, zahlen]
```

---

EDIT: Just spotted that you are Polish, so Polish example below:

```
final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
        "pięć", "piec", "Pieczka", "pięść", "pieczęć", "pieczątka");
Collections.sort(strings, Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL")));
System.out.println(strings);
// output: [piec, pieczątka, pieczęć, Pieczka, pięć, pięść]
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! ;) Actually, I found even simplier solution: `Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
collator.setDecomposition(Collator.CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION);
collator.compare(one, two)` The second example here shows what the `CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION` rule does: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html

Comment: Beware, `Collator.getInstance()` without explicit `Locale` is environment-dependant: it _Returns a Collator instance which is appropriate for the **user's default Locale**. See "[Be wary of the default locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale)"._

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but I'm in doubt now. I need sorted data only for displaying to the user, not sending it to somewhere or calculating something... So probably the default locale is enough? But if I would like to correctly sort german and danish characters and use them as machine-output, then the best choice would be to use  `Local.US` locale?

Comment: An update! It is good to use an explicit `Locale` after all! When I changed the locale of my phone to german, it omitted special characters, so the `CANNONICAL_DECOMPOSITION` isn't enough, you were right!

Answer (score 0):

A collator should also have a strength set beside the decomposition strategy:

```
final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
collator.setDecomposition(Collator.CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION);
collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
```

`Collator.CANONICAL_DECOMPOSITION` and a `Collator.SECONDARY` strength are required to sort accents/ umlauts; a full decomposition can be helpful if you want to sort unicode based characters; but this slows down sorting and requires more memory.